# How to use PuttyGen.exe when moving key(s) from old machine to a new machine?

Tags: ssh, putty, public-key, private-key, puttygen

I've only generated the public/private key pair in PuttyGen.exe once.  This was the first time I've ever used this tool.  Rather than having the folks hosting the server that I'm connecting to, who installed the public key, how can I avoid that, and just move things to Putty.exe on my new machine?

The first time I used this tool, I simply clicked the "Generate" button, and keep moving my mouse in the white space below the progress bar so the key pair was generated with random values (perhaps from the mouse movements?).  Then emailed the public key to the folks hosting the server I'm connecting to with Putty.  And I moved the private key into Putty for my connection to that server, under Connection > SSH > Auth (in Putty)

Then I changed the port and destination under Connection > SSH > Tunnels (in Putty) and clicked "Add".  I think I also entered my user name into Connection > Data (in Putty) before all of this.

https://linhost.info/2010/12/windows-generate-ssh-key-pairs-with-puttygen/

Do I need to use the "Load an existing private key file" "Load" button in this tool somehow?  (by just using the old key pair from my old machine?)  What other steps are needed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to use this tool again.  I simply loaded the old private key into Connection > SSH > Auth > Browse, in a brand new Putty session on my new machine.